# PHP Foreach error while uploading product image in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Any help with this problem appreciated, when I am uploading a product image from back end admin panel, I am getting this error.

```
Warrning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/AMPPS/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/NotProtectedExtension.php on line 91
```

After doing a bit of debugging I understood that

```
$extensions = $helper->getProtectedFileExtensions()
```

is returning null and hence the foreach error.

I haven't uploaded any images recently so I don't know what particular change triggered this.

Answer (score 8):

Figured out the problem after wasting a day in debugging the error

I might have messed with the setup script and that inserted the below row in ***core_config_data*** table

```
path => 'general', value => NULL
```

That resulted in the config tree for 'general' to point to NULL and hence the key

```
'general/file/protected_extensions'
```

was never descendable. Since the database values are populated and added later on after the fetching config values from the xml files, the above row obliterated all keys starting with the path ***general***

Comment: I too had the same issue and resolution, but my value was 1.  No idea how it got inserted.  Can you mark this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have this:

```
<protected_extensions>
    <!-- PHP script file extension -->
    <php>php</php>
    <!-- File extension of configuration of an Apache Web server -->
    <htaccess>htaccess</htaccess>
    <!-- Java script file extension -->
    <jsp>jsp</jsp>
    <!-- Perl script file extension -->
    <pl>pl</pl>
    <!-- Python script file extension -->
    <py>py</py>
    <!-- Active Server Page script file extension -->
    <asp>asp</asp>
    <!-- UNIX command prompt file extension -->
    <sh>sh</sh>
    <!-- Common Gateway Interface script extension type -->
    <cgi>cgi</cgi>
    <!-- BOF HTML file extensions -->
    <htm>htm</htm>
    <html>html</html>
    <phtml>phtml</phtml>
    <shtml>shtml</shtml>
    <!-- EOF HTML file extensions -->
</protected_extensions>
```

in `app\code\Core\Magento\Core\etc\config.xml` (lines 377-400 in Magento 1.7.0.1).

If not, you have edited a core file, which is not a good idea. If it is there, check your db, core_config_table, path='general/file/protected_extensions'. There shouldn't be anything.
Finally, check in the config.xml of other modules (community and local) if there is a default value set for this parameter, a block like:

```
<config>
    ....
    <default>
        ....
        <general>
            <file>
                <protected_extensions>
                    ....
                </protected_extensions>
            </file>
        </general>
    </default>
        ....
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks OSdave for the quick reply, I tried all 3 of your suggestions, everything is as expected but still the same